# One-Hot Encoding on data Destroys Model?

Tags: one-hot-encoding

I have a feature in my data that represents different types of accounts (it's basically numbers, like 15, 2, 40, etc...).
I decided to use one-hot encoding on that column using get_dummies().

The model is handling a fraud detection problem, so i have approximately 1% of the data which is fraud.
Before performing one-hot, the model is capable of predicting some fraud.
After the one-hot - it predicts nothing. 0.

I assume it's because of the one-hot encoding - it produces many features, and it might be not productive.

Does that make sense? What can I do in that case?
Thanks!

Comment: looks like the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) and [class imbalance problems](https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-imbalanced-classes-in-machine-learning-d43d6fa19d2) combined